# How can I share query data between different subreports using Pentaho Report Designer?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

Good day community, the question I have is about how I can share values ​​between subreportes, I am currently designing a report using the Pentaho Report Designer tool, which has different subreportes, and in each subreport I need to use some of the data that contains another ( s) subreporte (s) through the use of formulas (As in Excel you can use the data from one sheet in another), but trying to make the formulas only allows me to access the data belonging to the subreporte that I am editing .

Example:

Subreport 1 contains: id, name, age, weight, height.

Subreport 2 contains: count(subreport1!id), average (subreport1!age), average (subreporte1!weight), average (subreporte1!height).

This is required because each subreport should appear on a different sheet once the report has been generated in excel format.

I have been looking for information about how to do this, but I can not find something that is useful or that can give me an idea of ​​how to make that implementation. For what I would appreciate if you can guide me.

Comment: as per my understanding of your issue : Basic funda of sub-report is you can use different data-source(query), so when you create a sub-report add another query which gives you the count as per your requirement.

Comment: I have never used this function myself so I can't guarantee, but in your Subreport, select the Data tab, scroll all the way down to "Parameters", right-click, "Edit Sub-report parameters". There, you can import parameters from the parent report on the left and export subreport-parameters to the parent. You could try adding your values to Export.